# Spring Static methods

Tags: java, spring, static

I am learning Spring, and the book I am reading has the following code line

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Why is it needed the static keyword, is it normal to declare the `@Bean` annotation on static methods, if it is, why ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193365/what-in-the-world-are-spring-beans) might help.

Comment: It's needed for that *specific* type because the "placeholder" system is what's used to fill in expressions like `${server.port}`. It's used in bootstrapping the entire configuration and so has to be available before everything gets going.

Comment: Consider also other sources of truth, beside the book you are reading, like the spring official reference documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` object is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, so, according to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

> Special consideration must be taken for `@Bean` methods that return
>   Spring `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (BFPP) types. Because **BFPP objects
>   must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle**, they can
>   interfere with processing of annotations such as `@Autowired`, `@Value`,
>   and `@PostConstruct` within `@Configuration` classes. To avoid these
>   lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning `@Bean` methods as `static`.
>
> **By marking this method as static, it can be invoked without causing
>   instantiation of its declaring `@Configuration` class, thus avoiding the
>   above-mentioned lifecycle conflicts.** Note however that static `@Bean`
>   methods will not be enhanced for scoping and AOP semantics as
>   mentioned above. This works out in BFPP cases, as they are not
>   typically referenced by other `@Bean` methods. As a reminder, a
>   WARN-level log message will be issued for any non-static `@Bean` methods
>   having a return type assignable to `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.