# How to use @Autowired annotation two or more different Component class for same service?

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

For example, have a class like as follows.
First `XService service` in class `A` is not null but second `XService service` in `AmountValidator` is null.I get `NullPointerException` I try to create bean `new` it works and then I get same exception when call `AmountValidateService outsideRestService` in `XService`.
How can I  use `XService` everywhere that I use `@Autowired` annotation.

My main class:

```
@Service
 class A extends AbstractA implements  IA {    
 @Autowired
 XService service; //first autowired definition. code go to check() method. service not null now.

public doSometing(){
    validator.check();
    service.methodA();
    super.AbstractMethod();
  }
}
```

Validator class used in class A :

```
 class Validator<T> implements IValidator<T> {
         public void check(){
             rule.check(); // rule have a implements IValidator eg: amountValidator, dateValidator class
          }
        }
```

AmountValidator added to rule in class Validator.

```
@Component
class AmountValidator implements IValidator<T>{
@Autowired
XService service; // code comes here service is null. same service class mentioned above class A.

@Override
public void check(){
     service.validateAmount(); // nullPointerException.
  }
}
```

My main Service

```
@Component
class XService {
@Autowired 
AmountValidateService outsideRestService;

public validateAmount(){
    outsideRestService.validate(); // nullPointer when create XService with the `New` keyword
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the class definition for AmountValidateService? Also please tidy up the code and question, its a little hard to grasp at first

Comment: `AmountValidateService` classic service class that have `@service` annotation.  Sorry for complex question. I clean the question for more understanble.

Comment: Do you create instance of AmountValidator yourself with new keyword or it is creating BY context? @Autowired works only for context created instance cause injection is produced BY spring context.

Comment: I see you've edited the code, and still notice this `class AmountValidator() ...` are the parenthesis intended?

Comment: I know there are some parts that make the code a bit complex, but I used a strategy patter, I didn't know how to explain it. The AmountValidator class has been added to the rules in the Starategy class. see: Validataor class rule. And I never created intance for AmountValidator.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error cause you are trying to create components/beans/services yourself. As i mentioned in comment when you create components yourself it - `@Autowired` doesn't work - thats you've got NPE

Comment: what does 'you create components yourself' mean?  Components doesn't create by Spring anyway. I create a component and I try to call service. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

All classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Service` are considered special classes which are instantiated by Spring automatically via [DI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html), instantiating them with `new` defeats the purpose of [DI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html).

These special classes are named [`Spring Beans`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193365/what-in-the-world-are-spring-beans).

Every time the application starts, the framework instances all `Spring Beans`, and all `@Autowired` fields are injected by Spring automatically. But the `Spring Beans` must be defined somewhere in the class path. Else you will receive a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

As an attempt to answer the question, since I don't have a stack trace nor all the Spring Bean definitions:

When you instantiate `XService` using `new XService()` your new instance will not actually initialize the field `AmountValidateService outsideRestService`, effectively leaving it as `null`.

You may set the field yourself but as I mentioned earlier, it defeats the purpose of [DI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html)

Your question is not complex, it is incomplete.