# @Autowired object is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to autowire jdbctemplate in MessageBoxDAO class (which i guess is working fine), then i create autowired DAO object in the controller to get the latest ID in order to counter not getting repetitive IDs and start where it ended.

Here's the code:

```
@Component
public class MessageBoxDAO {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

...

    public long getLatestID() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT id FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", Integer.class);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class MessageBoxController {

    @Autowired
    MessageBoxDAO dao;

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(dao.getLatestID());

...
}
```

For some unknown to me reason "dao" is null, hence counter cannot be constructed and the program stops

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.CRUD.MessageBoxController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.CRUD.MessageBoxDAO.getLatestID()" because "this.dao" is null
```

I'm new to spring boot and I understand it might be a very simple problem, but can somebody point out where am I being wrong?

Comment: Field injection happens after the object is constructed. Field initialisation happens during construction. Use constructor injection and initialise `counter` in your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counter` is a member variable of MessageBoxController. Spring use reflection to construct MessageBoxController instance. It would be initialized before dependency injection of dao. More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443630/6644123
We can try to rewrite counter's initialization time.
An example may be like code below:

```
@RestController
public class MessageBoxController {
    @Autowired
    MessageBoxDAO dao;

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        // initialize counter after dependency injection of dao
        counter.set(dao.getLatestID());
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're facing is due to initialization of the following object

```
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(dao.getLatestID());
```

You've `Autowired` the `MessageBoxDAO` dependency which is not initialized at the time of execution of the above instruction. Either you should initialize the counter after the completion of instantization process or use construction injection.