# What does it mean that Spring framework has a "POJO implementation"

Tags: java, spring, pojo

I read somewhere that "Spring framework is lightweight because of its POJO implementation".
But what does "POJO implementation" mean?

Comment: POJO is just plain old java object ,Please elaborate more what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the important principles of Spring is that it wants to help you to create [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) software - which means that there should be no unnecessary dependencies between the components of your software.

One of the ways it does this is by allowing you to work with [POJOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) (Plain Old Java Objects) - just simple Java classes that don't need to extend classes or implement interfaces from the Spring Framework, and that don't need dependencies on other parts of the framework.

Since these POJO classes don't have any dependencies on the framework, you can easily reuse them in other applications where you are not using the Spring Framework.

It also helps to understand the history of the Spring Framework. Many years ago, when [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) (or J2EE, as it was known then) was new, it was hard to create an [EJB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans). You had to implement special J2EE interfaces and implement special lifecycle methods. This made it hard to use. The Spring Framework was created as a reaction to this. In contrast to J2EE, you could implement your business logic in simple POJO classes without the complicated boilerplate code that J2EE required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this statement is true "Spring framework is lightweight because of its POJO implementation. ". I think you misread it. Lightweight and POJO implementations are 2 unrelated concepts (and i don't think Spring is lightweight).
POJO is short for Plain old java object, an application implemented in pojo way means the logic resides in POJO with little to no boilerplate code, thus it's very portable. An PoJo application can be ported from Spring to another container with little modification.

I think the original messages should be: "Spring application is portable because of its POJO implementation. "

Answer (score 0):

Spring is LightWeight because of many reasons one being it's components are loosely couples.

For example, **you can use Spring JDBC without Spring MVC.**

Compare it to for example Java EE.  If you want to run a Java EE application, you can't just create a small application that will run on its own.

You will need a Java EE application server to run your application, such as Glassfish, WebLogic or WebSphere.

Most application servers are big and complex pieces of software, that are not trivial to install and configure.  You don't need such a thing with Spring.

You can use for example Spring dependency injection in any small, standalone programe

There are other good answer which might help in understanding more in detail

[What makes the Spring framework a lightweight container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117166/what-makes-the-spring-framework-a-lightweight-container)

https://dzone.com/articles/why-spring-framework-is-popular

https://coderanch.com/t/639696/frameworks/Spring-called-Lightweight-framework